# Is the breath attack gained from the spell Draconic Transformation able to travel through an Antimagic Field or Tiny Hut?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Draconic Transformation is a 7th-level spell from the book Fizban's Treasury of Dragons states:

> With a roar, you draw on the magic of dragons to transform yourself, taking on draconic features. You gain the following benefits until the spell ends:
>
> **Blindsight**...
>
> **Breath Weapon.** When you cast this spell, and as a bonus action on subsequent turns for the duration, you can exhale shimmering energy in a 60-foot cone. Each creature in that area must make a Dexterity saving throw, taking 6d8 force damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one
>
> **Wings**...

Sage advice compendium ruling for determining if something is magical:

> Is it a magic item?
>
> Is it a spell? Or does it let you create the effects of a spell that’s mentioned in its description?
>
> Is it a spell attack?
>
> Is it fueled by the use of spell slots?
>
> Does its description say it’s magical?

Likewise, would the 2nd level spell "Dragon's Breath" do so as well?

For clarification on why I think it might, I'm not sure if the effect of the Breath Weapon gained from Draconic Transformation is innately magical in and of itself as it is not directly a spell nor mimic an effect of a spell similar to how the Eladrin Variant elf had "Fey Step" which allows them to cast Misty Step (effect of a spell).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Spell effects cannot the pass through a *tiny hut* or *antimagic field*.

*Tiny hut* states:

> Spells and other magical effects can't extend through the dome or be cast through it.

Since *draconic transformation* and *dragon’s breath* are spells, their effects cannot pass through the dome of hut.

*Antimagic field* yields a similar result, since it states:

> Spells and other magical effects, except those created by an artifact or a deity, are suppressed in the sphere and can't protrude into it.

The effects of a spell are always magical, *unless the spell description explicitly tells you otherwise*, as is the case with *wall of stone*:

> A nonmagical wall of solid stone springs into existence at a point you choose within range.